# VMWARE issue removing vmci module

Tags: unix, filesystems, vmware, fedora

I have a fedora 20 virtual machine running on VMware Lab manager (4.0.4.1406).

I am trying to install the VMware tools provided by Lab manager.

When I run the install script i get the below output

```
[root@config5269VM0 vmware-tools-distrib]# ./vmware-install.pl 
The following VMware kernel modules have been found on your system that were 
not installed by the VMware Installer.  Please remove them then run this 
installer again.

vmci

I.e. - 'rm /lib/modules/3.14.4-200.fc20.x86_64/misc/<ModuleName>.{o,ko}'

Execution aborted.
```

I then tried to find the vmci module on my machine

```
[root@config5269VM0 vmware-tools-distrib]# find / -name vmci
/dev/vmci
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmci
/sys/class/misc/vmci
/home/u350932/vmware-tools-distrib/lib/include/vmci
```

I then tried to remove the directories

```
/sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmci
/sys/class/misc/vmci


[root@config5269VM0 vmware-tools-distrib]# rm -rf /sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmci
rm: cannot remove ‘/sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmci/dev’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmci/power/control’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmci/power/async’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmci/power/runtime_enabled’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmci/power/runtime_active_kids’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmci/power/runtime_active_time’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmci/power/autosuspend_delay_ms’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmci/power/runtime_status’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmci/power/runtime_usage’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmci/power/runtime_suspended_time’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmci/subsystem’: Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove ‘/sys/devices/virtual/misc/vmci/uevent’: Operation not permitted
[root@config5269VM0 vmware-tools-distrib]# rm -rf /sys/class/misc/vmci
rm: cannot remove ‘/sys/class/misc/vmci’: Operation not permitted
```

I tried finding out this error. I checked the file permissions and attributes

```
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 0 May 28 09:39 vmci

lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./vmci
```

I tried to find more information on these errors. As far as I can tell it is some issue with how the files are mounted but I'm a little bit lost to be honest.

```
[root@config5269VM0 misc]# mount
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs
(rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=1014952k,nr_inodes=253738,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts
(rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup
(rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mapper/fedora-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs
(rw,relatime,fd=29,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime,seclabel)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,seclabel)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,seclabel)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse
(rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/dev/sr0 on /run/media/u350932/VMware Tools type iso9660 (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500,uhelper=udisks2)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a futile attempt. Fedora 20 already comes with VMware installed...